# Chain Commands in Sqlite: .print dot-command not Working

Tags: sqlite

I can chain commands in sqlite like:

```
$ sqlite3 test.sqlite .tables .schema "select * from object_store"
```

However, when I try to use `.print` dot-command, it gives error.

```
$ sqlite3 test.sqlite .print "The Tables Are:" .tables
Error: near "The": syntax error
```

How to print string when chaining commands in sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Have to wrap the dot-command and its arguments with `"`.

```
sqlite3 -cmd ".print The Tables Are:\n" -cmd ".tables" test.sqlite .quit
```

or,

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite ".print The Tables Are:\n" ".tables"
```